# android create custom theme

Tags: android, themes

I want to extent default android AppTheme. What should I write here instead of android:Theme?

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html) and [this](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/01/create-custom-theme-inheriting.html) post. Probably this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the Theme you want to use as parent, actually.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
```

etc.

Use the name that appears when in Graphical Layout (in Eclipse):
[image: Check this menu]

Also, and of course, [Android reference is your best friend](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)